# Transact SQL sub query

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I would like a single query which will return a list of Order_IDs for orders where all the order line items are in stock. Here are the tables to illustrate:

test_Order:

```
Order_ID
1001
1002
1003
```

test_OrderLine:

```
OrderLine_ID|Order_ID|Item_ID|Quantity
10|1001|101|1
11|1001|102|1
12|1001|103|1
13|1002|101|4
14|1002|102|1
15|1003|101|1
16|1003|104|4
```

test_Item:

```
Item_ID|InStockQuantity
101|3
102|1
103|7
```

So in the example above only Order_ID 1001 should be returned because:

- In order 1001, all 3 items in OrderLines have a quantity less or equal to the InStockQuantity in Items.
- In order 1002, item 101 has a quantity of 4 but there are only 3 in stock.
- In order 1003, item 104 does not exist in the Items table.

This is obviously not correct but something like:

```
SELECT O.Order_ID
FROM test_Order AS O
  LEFT JOIN test_OrderLine OL
    ON O.Order_ID = OL.Order_ID
  LEFT JOIN test_Item I
    ON OL.Item_ID = I.Item_ID
WHERE (OL.Quantity <= I.InStockQuantity)
GROUP BY O.Order_ID
```

The problem with that query is that only ONE of the OrderLines needs to have a Quantity <= InStockQuantity for its Order_ID to appear in the results, whereas I only want it to appear in the results if ALL Quantities in the order are <= InStockQuantities.

I read something about “ALL” operator but can’t see how that would work in a subquery.

Comment: How about a stored proc that takes the order_id as input then creates a temp table where it iterates through each item_id and checks the requested/ordered quantity against the stock quantity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different way to think about this problem is to return the order_ids that don't have order lines that require a quantity greater than what's in stock. Using a left join and `coalesce` could allow you treat items that are out of stock completely as though they have a quantity of 0:

```
SELECT order_id
FROM   test_order
WHERE  order_id NOT IN (SELECT    order_id
                        FROM      test_orderline o
                        LEFT JOIN test_item i ON o.item_id = i.item_id 
                        WHERE     o.quantity > COALESCE(i.instockquantity, 0))
```

Comment: This would work if you change `and` to `where` in your subquery. As it is now, it (the subquery) will return all `order_id`s.

Answer (score 0):

Using `not exists()`:

```
select o.Order_id
from test_Order as o
where not exists (
    select 1
    from test_OrderLine as ol
      left join test_Item as i
        on ol.Item_id = i.Item_id
    where ol.Order_id = o.Order_id
      and OL.Quantity > coalesce(I.InStockQuantity,0)
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/JGHQ62465

returns:

```
+----------+
| Order_id |
+----------+
|     1001 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle: http://rextester.com/UPC62237

I believe this would work for your needs. I commented so you can understand the logic behind the query.

```
create table test_Order ([Order_id] int); 
insert into test_Order ([Order_id]) values 
 (1001)
,(1002)
,(1003);
create table test_OrderLine ([OrderLine_id] int, [Order_id] int, [Item_id] int, [Quantity] int) ; 
insert into test_OrderLine ([OrderLine_id], [Order_id], [Item_id], [Quantity]) values 
 (10, 1001, 101, 1) 
,(11, 1001, 102, 1)
,(12, 1001, 103, 1)
,(13, 1002, 101, 4)
,(14, 1002, 102, 1)
,(15, 1003, 101, 1)
,(16, 1003, 104, 4)
;
create table test_Item ([Item_id] int, [InStockQuantity] int) ; 
insert into test_Item ([Item_id], [InStockQuantity]) values 
 (101, 3)
,(102, 1)
,(103, 7)
;

select original_orderline_count.Order_id 
/*first table gets each order with it's line count*/
from (select order_line.Order_id, count(order_line.OrderLine_id) as line_count
        from test_OrderLine order_line
        group by order_line.Order_id) as original_orderline_count
/*second table gets count of order lines in stock by order*/
inner join (select ol.Order_id, count(ol.OrderLine_id) as line_count
            from test_Order o
            inner join test_OrderLine ol on o.Order_id = ol.Order_id
            inner join test_Item i on i.Item_id = ol.Item_id
            where ol.Quantity <= i.InStockQuantity
            group by ol.Order_id) as orderline_in_stock
/*join the two tables on order id line count matching*/         
on original_orderline_count.Order_id = orderline_in_stock.Order_id
and original_orderline_count.line_count = orderline_in_stock.line_count
```